# Holding weights on bench press flyes

Tags: strength, strength-training, stretching, stronglifts, bench-press

[image]

After my regular 4 sets of flyes, I  do one more set with heavy weight stretching my pectorals as long as I can just like the image attached, Stretching can last 10 to 15 seconds depending upon the weights that I use.

I would like your critics on this stretching workout of mine. 
I would like to know how safe is this workout in the long run.

Comment: You're gonna have to critique it yourself. I don't do that kind of stretch with heavy weights, because my pectoralis starts acting up. Besides, I do my stretching after the workout, and get it done then. You should be careful, but you should be your own judge. If it doesn't hurt, it's probably fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll preface this by saying this is purely my opinion based on many years of training and experience as a trainer.

I, personally, would not perform *“one more set with heavy weight stretching my pectorals as long as I can “* after 4 sets of regular flyes.  Assuming hard work with heavy weights, your shoulders and pectoral muscles will be pretty exhausted.  Adding heavy weight and holding the stretch as long as you can, will force your shoulders and pectorals to counteract the force of gravity.  This could leave you susceptible to strains and tears of the pectoral, and, rotator cuff injuries.

> Causes of a pectoral strain
>
> A pectoral strain often occurs suddenly due to a high force going
>   through the muscle and tendon beyond what it can withstand. This
>   typically occurs during weight training especially when performing a
>   bench press, chest press or **pectoral flys** (especially with free
>   weights).
>
> Sometimes a pectoral strain may develop over time due to **repetitive or
>   prolonged activities** placing strain on the pectoral muscles. This may
>   cause gradual degeneration and weakening of the pectorals predisposing
>   them to further injury. Pectoral strains tend to occur more commonly
>   in the older athlete and particularly following an inadequate warm-up.
>   (http://www.physioadvisor.com.au/14703550/pectoral-strain-torn-pectoral-physioadvisor.htm)

And, since there's no definitive study to suggest that stretching the pectorals like you do adds any benefit, why risk injury?  Especially since while lying flat, your shoulders and pectorals will act like levers resisting the weight and force of gravity.

Answer (score 1):

Stretching chest for any long wont make it look better or bigger. Ppl do it bc how these exercices make'm feel after.

I do stretchs for warm up. With elastics or low weight. 15-20sec.

Little advice. If you keep doing your 15sec don't hold breath for that long. If you do it standing, stretch abs and keep'em contracted all along these 15 secs. Then you will be working core and chest at once.

If you ends up liking functional exercices, try to do some workouts with TXR. Best exercices ever :-)

Comment: I forgot to mention. Breathe out from the beginning of the exercice up to the ment of maximum contraction, hold for 10 seconds and then Get breath while returning harms up to the initial position. You will improve also your 
anaerobic capacity